# Read only attribute lost when saving a file using file download dialog

Tags: c#, file-io, filesystems

A *xlsm* file with read only attribute exists in a temp folder. The same file will be saved using a file download dialog. While saving, the read only property gets lost, and the file is saved as not read only.

Comment: Well you can't really save a file that is readonly? Can you?

Comment: 1. save the file 2. set it as read only.

Comment: well we can save it in another drive with the same name.

Comment: FileInfo fileObj = new FileInfo(tempFileLocation);
            fileObj.IsReadOnly = true; . I was able to save the file in temp as read only. but when retrieving it nad save using filedownload in desktop it is getting as read only deleted.

Comment: a) In general including some code is useful, b) including a link to a file on your local PC will not work.

Comment: FileInfo fileObj = new FileInfo(tempFileLocation); fileObj.IsReadOnly = true; . I was able to save the file in temp as read only. but when retrieving it nad save using filedownload in desktop it is getting as read only deleted.

Comment: Directory Listing -- /temp/ 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[To Parent Directory]

   Tuesday, February 08, 2011 07:53 PM        <dir> EOCMaster
   Tuesday, February 08, 2011 07:53 PM        <dir> Extract
     Thursday, March 10, 2011 08:40 PM        <dir> SubSum
   Tuesday, February 08, 2011 07:53 PM        <dir> Upload
    Monday, December 05, 2011 07:24 PM      341,199 abc.xlsm(read only). while saving it gets removed

Comment: @user352588:  Please don't put code in the comments.  Rather, edit your question and add the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the file, do:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: how do i get the file path in file downlaod dialog

Comment: @user352588: [`FileDialog.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filename.aspx)